# Getting Path of image in html image tag.so how can i get URL of image from <img> tag?

Tags: html, asp.net, telerik, radeditor

I am using telerik rad image editor. When I upload images, I am using the `radimage.content` keyword to get its url but am getting url like html image tag. So I cannot use it in another control because it is in html tag, not simple url format.

Is there any keyword to get url from telerik radimageeditor or take url from html image tag? `Image = reImage.Content;` is used to get url but now am getting html image tag.

[image: radimage editor]

Comment: please help me to solve the problem

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to indented your question body and code sample so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit in to provide any additional detail that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

str = reImageAdd.Content; ;

```
            // Grab just the "src" attribute containing your image
            images = Regex.Match(str, "src=\"([^\"]*)\"").Groups[1].Value; // yields "http//www.abc.com/phoneimage.jpg"
```

first save the content into a string .now that string str contain like  then by using 2nd block of code we can find  path and filter path and save to another string so we can save to database that string